# How to get colormap plots to fill area?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm relatively new to visualization with python. I'm trying to visually show correlation between attributes using a color map, but for some reason the plots aren't filling the entire graph (see pic). 
[image: correlation color map]

Also, I understand the ticks are bunched (there's 34 attributes), but I wanted to fix the fill issue first. For reference here is the code I have:

```
correlation = wounds.corr()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(correlation,cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ticks = np.arange(0,len(wounds.columns),1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(wounds.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(wounds.columns)
plt.savefig('correlation.jpg')
plt.show()
```

This is my first time posting here so forgive me if anything is wrong with my question.

Edit: Added code for reference

Comment: Are you sure `correlation` and `wounds.columns` have the same dimension?

Comment: Please make sure to add a snippet of the code as part of the question, otherwise people will vote you down

Comment: @Kohn1001 thanks for the heads up. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Not sure about `matshow`. There is a very similar `imshow`:  `ax.imshow(correlation,cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1,extent=[-0.5,N-0.5,-0.5,N-0.5])` with `N=len(wounds.columns)`

Comment: What is the data type of the blank columns?

Comment: @WilliamMiller it's an int. More specifically, it's a binary attribute and the entire column is 0

Comment: Can you add the data? Or at least a subset of it or some manufactured data which replicates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use **pandas profiling** 
Try it out! **it would change your life :)**

(you can use it directly in your Jupyter notebook):

```
import pandas_profiling
report = df.profile_report(style={'full_width':True})
```

If you data is really big you can sample it randomly:

```
report = df.sample(100000).profile_report(style={'full_width':True})
```

And you can save it to a file:

```
report.to_file(output_file="profiling_report.html")
```